# What is the effect on fluid shear force by changing the distance between two surfaces?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Scenario…

Consider two “drums” of differing diameters, one nested inside another, both centered coaxialy, to form a gap between the two. The outer drum is 60cm diameter and the inner drum is 40cm diameter. The ‘gap’ between the two surfaces will be 10cm.

Fill the gap with a non-compressible newtonian fluid (e.g. water or high viscosity oil) and cap it off to make a closed system.

Now, hold the outer drum stationary (0 RPM) and apply a force to the inner drum axle to spin it at a fixed (10 RPM). The shear rate of the fluid will require a certain amount of force applied to the inner drum to spin it at the 10 RPM. Thus, the outer surface is stationary and the inner surface is moving at 10 RPM.

Now change the outer drum diameter to 50cm, which results in a ‘narrower gap’ of 5cm (i.e. the two solid surfaces are now closer together). Keep the fluid exactly the same (other than the obvious volume change due to the smaller gap) and the inner drum RPM exactly the same at 10 RPM.

My hypothisis is that the shear rate is now ‘steeper’ becasue of the narrower gap, and it will require more force to be applied to the inner drum axle to maintain the constant 10 RPM.

Is this correct? By only changing the gap between the two surfaces the amount of input force required to maintain a constant RPM will change… less force with a wider gap and more force with a narrower gap.

Comment: This assessment is correct.